# async Callback in for loop Fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am writing a Node JS function which have array of objects and for each item of it I need to call async function

```
for (var i = 0; i < allCases.length; i++) {

    if (allCases[i].Case_ID != null) {
        Utils.findAndUpdate(allCases[i], function(response) {
            console.log('received in the callback ', response);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('case id is null');
    }
}
```

findAndUpdate is a function which executes async calls and return the result in the callback. when i tried this on a single item it worked perfectly but within the loop it fails as the loop step over and reach the end while the callback is still happening.

i also tried this workaround to only increase the ' i ' in the callback success. but it leads to infinite loop

```
for (let i = 0; i < allCases.length;) {

    if (allCases[i].Case_ID != null) {
        Utils.findAndUpdate(allCases[i], function(response) {
            console.log('received in the callback ', response);
            i++;
        });
    } else {
        console.log('case id is null');
    }
}
```

i wonder how to solve this and why this workaround failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
allCases.forEach((case) => {
  if (case.Case_ID != null) {
      Utils.findAndUpdate(case, function (response) {
        console.log('received in the callback ', response);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('case id is null');
    }
  });
```

But if you want to chain requests, then you should should get rid of cycles

Comment: Thanks it worked. more explanation would be appreciated to your answer demonstrating why this approach worked. i also have a question how i would determine that i reached the last callback in the thread ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`IIFE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE);

```
for (let i = 0; i < allCases.length;) {

    if (allCases[i].Case_ID != null) {
        (function (i) {
            Utils.findAndUpdate(allCases[i], function (response) {
                console.log('received in the callback ', response);
            });
        })(i)

    } else {
        console.log('case id is null');
    }
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this also worked. i also have a question how i could determine that i reached the last callback in the thread ?

Comment: check the value of  `i` should be equal to length-1